# Pronunciation of 不: 불 vs 부

Tags: pronunciation, hanja

[不](http://m.hanja.naver.com/search/?query=%EF%A5%A7&mflag=1&direct=false) can be pronounced either 불 or 부 depending on the word ([examples](http://m.hanja.naver.com/search/word?query=%E4%B8%8D&mflag=1&direct=false)). Is there a rule or pattern when to which one or is it just a matter of memorizing word by word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a couple of documents:

1) ['미채택', '불채택', '부채택'의 차이](http://krdic.naver.com/rescript_detail.nhn?seq=4548)

When 不 is pronounced as '부', it is because the following noun usually starts with 'ㄷ' or 'ㅈ'. Examples are 부도덕(immoral), 부정확(imprecise), etc.

2) ['부실'과 '불실'](http://krdic.naver.com/rescript_detail.nhn?seq=1264)

There are a few exceptions, such as '부실(不實)', however since the proportion of vocabulary meeting the condition is large, the rule is still valid according to National Institute of the Korean Language.